# Does .net 4.5 support NFC Proximity API

Tags: c#, .net, nfc

I am trying to write a desktop app for Windows 7 using NFC technology.

I could not find any API for it.

The Proximity API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212057.aspx 
can only support Windows 8, it is disappointing.

Where can I found a API for NFC that is not tied to a manufacturer?

Comment: Anything in the `Windows.` namespace has dependencies on the version of windows that the app is running on, that is why it is under `Windows.` instead of `System.`

Answer (score 2):

I had success using [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) and NDEF Library (via nuget) together with reader hardware from ACS and Mifare Tags.

pcsc-sharp only provides access to the PC/SC API (which is supported by readers from multiple manufacturers). You still have to write the whole communication flow yourself. The flow itself depends on which cards you are going to use. Mifare Classic for example provides access control, therefore you need to authenticate every block first before you read or write. Simpler cards like the Mifare Ultralight don't need this step. The cards itself often vary vastly in terms of how the memory is organized.

Recommended reading:

- specifications at [NFC-Forum](http://nfc-forum.org)
- documentation of the cards you are using (provided by the manufacturer)
- SDK documentation of your reader
- examples in the pcsc-sharp repository